# How to connect to a elasticache AWS memcache and retrieve a record in java? I cant find any code examples online

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, memcached, amazon-elasticache

I am looking through the aws documentation and searched on google but I can't find any documentation that says how to do this with the java sdk. Can someone share any code that they have or point me to some code examples which shows how to dothis?

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't use the AWS SDK to retrieve a record from an Elasticache Memcached instance, you would use a [Java Memcached library](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=memcached%20java).